# Need help debugging segfault

Tags: c

I do not know whats wrong with my code.  It is compiling correctly but at output it shows second image.  Output tell me what is wrong with code and it must give output as shown in first image.

The code must run like this:
[image: code must run like this]

But shows this:
[image: but shows this]

I do not know what is wrong in which block.  It is a code which is used to check whether the input string will get accepted or not .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char *arr[1][3]= {{"aABb","c","d"}};
    char input[15]= {'\0'};
    char temp[15]= {'\0'};
    char stack[15]= {'$','S'};
    int ip=0;
    int ct=0;
    int top,i;
    char x;
    clrscr();
    printf("\t\t\t Predictive parser\t\t\t\n");
    printf("___________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("The grammar is :\n");
    printf("\t\tS-->aABb\n");
    printf("\t\tA-->c\n");
    printf("\t\tB-->d\n\n");
    printf("You have follow some rules\n");
    printf("The string must end with $\n");
    printf("Enter  the String  : ");
    gets(input);
    top=(strlen(stack))-1;
    x=stack[top];
    printf("_______________________________________________________\n");
    printf("stack\t\t\t input\t\t\t production\n");
    printf("________________________________________________________\n");
    while(x!='\0')
    {
        if(x=='S'&&input[ct]=='a')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t");
            for(i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\tderivation using S-->aABb\n");
            stack[top]='\0';
            strcpy(temp,strrev(arr[0][0]));
            strcat(stack,temp);
            top=strlen(stack)-1;
        }
        else if(x=='A'&&input[ct]=='c')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            strcpy(temp,strrev(arr[0][1]));
            strcat(stack,temp);
            top=strlen(stack)-1;
            printf("\t\t derivation usingA-->c\n");
        }
        else if(x=='B'&&input[ct]=='d')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            strcpy(temp,strrev(arr[0][2]));
            strcat(stack,temp);
            top=strlen(stack)-1;
            printf("\t\t derivation using B-->d\n");
        }
        else if(x=='a'&&input[ct]=='a')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping a from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='c'&&input[ct]=='c')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping c from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='d'&&input[ct]=='d')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping d from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='b'&&input[ct]=='b')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping b from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='$'&&input[ct]=='$')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            printf("\t\tSuccessfull\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            printf("\t\tUnsuccessfull\n");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        }
        x=stack[top];
    }
    printf("\n____________________ Exit program__________________");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: In any case, *warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast* all over, please check the types. Doesn't your compiler issue any diagnostics?

Comment: no warning in any case as u mention @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Then you might consider getting another C compiler. A proper C compiler which points out errors in your code is priceless when it comes to writing C code that actually works.

Comment: Hi, you appear to be using Turbo C. Not a lot of people still use Turbo C, and it is notorious for non conformance to the C standard. Strongly advise you to try a more modern dev env

Comment: i am using dev c++  @Srini

Comment: In that case, you have to modify this program. Stuff like `conio.h` if I remember correctly is a Borland exclusive header. Dev C++, albeit old, still used GCC which doesn't have a definition for `conio.h`. Please read [this](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/faq.html#conio). In any case it appears to be working fore you. Just a pointer that stuff may not work the same way you expect them to

Comment: after removal of conio.h same output only first block is ececuting and program is terminating u can try running on your system @Srini

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. They can be difficult or impossible to read, and can't be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is suspected `conio.h` and other outdated headers is this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* strrev(char *str)
{
      char *p1;
      int i, j;
      //puts("Reversing");
      //puts(str);
      p1 = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) * sizeof(char));
      for( i = strlen(str)-1, j =0; i >=0; i--, j++) {
        p1[j] = str[i];
      }
      p1[j] = '\0';
      puts(p1);
      //puts("Done");
      return p1;
}

void main()
{
    char *arr[1][3]= {{"aABb","c","d"}};
    char input[15]= {'\0'};
    char temp[15]= {'\0'};
    char stack[15]= {'$','S'};
    int ip=0;
    int ct=0;
    int top,i;
    char x;

    printf("\t\t\t Predictive parser\t\t\t\n");
    printf("___________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("The grammar is :\n");
    printf("\t\tS-->aABb\n");
    printf("\t\tA-->c\n");
    printf("\t\tB-->d\n\n");
    printf("You have follow some rules\n");
    printf("The string must end with $\n");
    printf("Enter  the String  : ");
    gets(input);
    top=(strlen(stack))-1;
    x=stack[top];
    printf("_______________________________________________________\n");
    printf("stack\t\t\t input\t\t\t production\n");
    printf("________________________________________________________\n");
    while(x!='\0')
    {
        if(x=='S'&&input[ct]=='a')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t");
            for(i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\tderivation using S-->aABb\n");
            stack[top]='\0';
            strcpy(temp,strrev(arr[0][0]));
            strcat(stack,temp);
            top=strlen(stack)-1;
        }
        else if(x=='A'&&input[ct]=='c')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            strcpy(temp,strrev(arr[0][1]));
            strcat(stack,temp);
            top=strlen(stack)-1;
            printf("\t\t derivation usingA-->c\n");
        }
        else if(x=='B'&&input[ct]=='d')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            strcpy(temp,strrev(arr[0][2]));
            strcat(stack,temp);
            top=strlen(stack)-1;
            printf("\t\t derivation using B-->d\n");
        }
        else if(x=='a'&&input[ct]=='a')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping a from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='c'&&input[ct]=='c')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping c from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='d'&&input[ct]=='d')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping d from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='b'&&input[ct]=='b')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            printf("\t\t popping b from the stack");
            input[ct]=' ';
            ct++;
            stack[top]='\0';
            top--;
        }
        else if(x=='$'&&input[ct]=='$')
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            printf("\t\tSuccessfull\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i<=strlen(stack); i++)
                printf("%c",stack[i]);
            printf("\t\t\t ");
            for (i=ip; i<6; i++)
                printf("%c",input[i]);
            stack[top]='\0';
            printf("\t\tUnsuccessfull\n");
            getchar();
            exit(1);
        }
        x=stack[top];
    }
    printf("\n____________________ Exit program__________________");
    getchar();
}
```

**The above is your code with some tiny modifications**

1. Used a custom `strrev` , very naive implementation with bad memory practices, but it works.
2. got rid of `conio`
3. Added `stdlib.h` for `malloc`
4. got rid of `getch` in favor of `getchar`
5. got rid of `clrscr()`

Nobody knows what bugs `conio` and the old Borland headers have. They might erroneously redescribe some std functions.

When I run the above with input `acdb$` I get

```
                        Predictive parser
___________________________________________________

The grammar is :
                S-->aABb
                A-->c
                B-->d

You have follow some rules
The string must end with $
Enter  the String  : acdb$
_______________________________________________________
stack                    input                   production
________________________________________________________

$S                      acdb$           derivation using S-->aABb
bBAa

$bBAa                    acdb$           popping a from the stack
$bBA                      cdb$c
                 derivation usingA-->c

$bBc                      cdb$           popping c from the stack
$bB                        db$d
                 derivation using B-->d

$bd                        db$           popping d from the stack
$b                          b$           popping b from the stack
$                            $          Successfull

____________________ Exit program__________________
```

Start using either gcc/clang and use gdb/lldb to debug these programs.

[here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf)'s a nice guide.

If you compile with these options you can see your program is rife with bad programming patterns

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic parser.c -o parser
parser.c: In function ‘strrev’:
parser.c:9:4: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90 [-Werror]
parser.c:9:4: error: (this will be reported only once per input file) [-Werror]
parser.c:11:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
parser.c:11:16: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [-Werror]
parser.c: At top level:
parser.c:21:6: error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
parser.c: In function ‘main’:
parser.c:52:23: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:66:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:80:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:94:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:108:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:122:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:136:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:150:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:161:24: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
parser.c:169:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
parser.c:169:13: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```